# Override default scroll behaviour target on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a page with a navbar with links on the same page. When i disable all js plugins and click on a link it "jumps" (without smooth scroll) to the anchored link.

But because i have a sticky header it's neccessary that i use a offset. Because of that i copied this nice piece of code from the web:

My "navbar"

```
<div id=myAffix>My Affix</div>
<a href="#2849">Example link</a>
```

The part of the html page:

```
<li id="2849" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
<h6>Example header</h6>
</li>
```

```
// Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
$("#myAffix a").on('click', function (event) {
    var offset = 125;
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();
        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;
        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - offset
        }, 800, function () {
            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    }  // End if
});
```

When i now click the link it smooth scrolls to that part (with the offset) and after that it "jumps" to the position without the offset. I tried to override default scroll behaviour, disable single js plugins but it keeps this behaviour. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: don't use jquery for this, just use [window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: thanx, that did the trick! why don't post this as an answer?